# While creating the app using app manager getting the issue

Tags: salesforce-lightning

while creating the Application using App manager in salesforce Lightning getting the below issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2edp.png)

can any one help me wit[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3uqr.png)h this why i am getting this issue?

i am expecting if some help me out with this screen shot issue?

At the time of creating the app with app manager in lightning  i am getting this error message

**An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again. Setup Entity ID is invalid: null**

Answer (score 0):

An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again. Setup Entity ID is invalid: null

I have faced same error it got resolved by removing lightning app from org

Root Cause: There were lot of apps in the current org.